# Confused with 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql

I am beginner at databases and I have small question.

What is the difference between these two queries?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductName LIKE '[C-M]%';

SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'C%' AND 'M%';
```

Comment: This question looks specific to the particular database engine. Someone should add a proper tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *You don't mention the DBMS product you are using, the following information applies to `SQL Server`.*

The first query will return all `Products` whose `ProductName` begins with any letter between `C` and `M`.  This list is inclusive.

```
Select  *
From    Products
Where   ProductName Like '[C-M]%';
```

Example output:

```
C
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
Golf
Hotel
...
Lima
M
Mike
```

The seconds query will return all of the `Products` whose `ProductName` is between `C%` and ending with the string literal `M%`.  (Note: `M%` is *not* using a wildcard.  It is the literal string `M%`).  This list is *not* inclusive.

```
Select  *
From    Products
Where   ProductName Between 'C%' And 'M%';
```

Example output:

```
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
Golf
Hotel
...
Lima
M
```

Comment: I checked PostgreSQL and SQLite and SQL-92 and they all agree `[C-M]%` should match any string literally starting with `[C-M]`.

Comment: @melpomene Then that might be some DBMS variance - in SQL Server, `LIKE '[C-M]%'` treats it as `LIKE C%` → `M%` alphabetically.

Comment: @melpomene Added a disclaimer.

Comment: I see. That seems to be a non-standard Microsoft extension.

Answer (score 0):

The first one returns products whose name starts with the string `[C-M]`.

The second one returns products whose name sorts alphabetically between `C%` and `M%`.

Comment: In SQL Server at least, the first one returns anything that starts with anything between C and M inclusive. Pretty sure that goes for most other SQL-compliant RDBMS's.

Comment: @GarethLyons https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE only lists `_` and `%` as metacharacters. ANSI SQL-92 agrees.

Comment: @GarethLyons http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like also only understands `_` and `%`.

Comment: cheers for the references. Seems only SQL Server uses the '[A-Z]' construct. Thought it was more general than that!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
where ProductName Like '[C-M]%';
```

will produce all rows where `ProductName` starts with any letter between `C` and `M`, including those like `Mzzzzzz`.

```
select * from Products 
where ProductName between 'C%' And 'M%';
```

In this query, the `%` is ***not*** a wildcard.  It is just another character literal. So this query will produce rows where `ProductName`, when sorted alphabetically, is equal to or Greater than (sorts after) the literal string `C%` and equal to or less than (sorts before) `M%`. It would ***not*** produce a row like `Mzzzzzz`.

It would produce row `C&` (sorts after `C%`), but would ***not*** produce row `C!` (sorts before `C%`) but it would produce row `M!` (sorts before `M%`)

The following script (SQL Server) will illustrate:

```
declare @t table 
(prodName varchar(10) not null)
insert @t(prodName)values
  ('C(apy'), ('C!ewrrt'), ('C@asdd'), ('C#qww'), 
  ('C%tty'), ('C&asda'),('C+ASD'),('C-ert'),('C=xx'),
  ('E(apy'), ('E!ewrrt'), ('F@asdd'), ('J#qww'), 
  ('G%tty'), ('N&asda'),('W+ASD'),('H-ert'),('J=xx'),
  ('M(apy'), ('M!ewrrt'), ('M@asdd'), ('M#qww'), 
  ('M%tty'), ('M&asda'),('M+ASD'),('M-ert'),('M=xx')

  select * from @t Where prodName like '[C-M]%'
  select * from @t Where prodName between 'C%' and 'M%'
  select * from @t order By prodName
```